# can native C **char be safely passed to managed C# delegate with paramter type "out string"?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, native, managed

In C:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CfgGetVariableString(const char *Name, char **Value)
{
    char StrValue[STR_MAX];
    int RetValue = GetVariableToStrValue(Name, StrValue, STR_MAX);
    if (RetValue == 0)
        *Value = StrValue;

    return RetValue;
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = DllCallingConvention)]        
private static extern int CfgGetVariableString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string name, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]out string value);
```

This does not work. I can make it work by calling CoTaskMemAlloc, but then I guess I should free it with separate managed to native call?

So what is the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: I'm curious and I might be wrong here, but are you allocating the `StrValue` array on the stack and then using it againt outside the scope of the `CfgGetVariableString` function by assigning the pointer to its first element to `*Value`?

Comment: This is the infamous [dangling pointer bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  Only works by accident in a C program, definitely won't work when you pinvoke it.  Solve the C bug first, the rest is then easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can make it work by calling `CoTaskMemAlloc`.

That is the only way that it can work. Because the marshaller will call `CoTaskMemFree` to deallocate the memory returned from the native function.

> I guess I should free it with separate managed to native call?

As mentioned above, that's not necessary because the framework already does so.

> What is the cleanest way to do it?

In my opinion the cleanest approach here, since you are already using a string length determined at compile time, is to have the caller allocate the memory. Change the type from `char**` to `char*`. Add an extra argument containing the length of the allocated string. Use `StringBuilder` on the C# side. There are countless examples of this pattern available here and indeed in other places so I don't feel any need to add to the canon.